# Email Etiquette: How was my email interpreted?

Tags: email

I recently wrote an email to a website owner.

I don't think my english skills are that bad, but its hard to read people through email.

> Hi!
>
> (Details about the bug I found...). I'm also a web developer, and am >looking for an internship. If you have an open spot, please email me. I'd >love to fix this bug, and many others for your company.
>
> Thanks for your time!
>
> Best Regards,
>   (firstname) (lastname)
>   [my url]

He responded a bit later:

> Excellent message by you. This is exactly how you should communicate with potential employers. We are looking into the issue you raise and will be in touch.

Generally people don't complement your email ettiqute directly, though I am a student, and this website's audience is students, who may or may not have the best emailing skills.

So my question:

Was he using sarcasm, or should I send him my resumé?

Also, my use of mailtrack and google analytics tells me that he clicked on my homepage link, if that changes anything

Comment: No harm in sending your resume.   What can you lose?

Comment: @Paparazzi True. I may do that anyways.

Comment: I don't think it is sarcasm, they say they will be in touch just be patient and see how you go. If you do respond simply thank them for the response they sent and say you look forward to hearing from them and hopefully working with them in future. Nice work to get the response, you could offer a path you might take to a solution next time and it might improve your chances again. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> love to fix this bug, and many others for your company

This wording is a bit awkward, as it implies that their website has many other bugs - which might be true, but being negative about something someone else owns is always problematic.

A single letter, like replacing "many" with "any", can change the tone. So my best advice is to have someone check texts that might affect your career *before* you send them, not afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't look sarcastic to me, but I wouldn't send my resume unless he asks for it.

Comment: Alright. Now, what do you recommend I do next in order to get this internship?

Comment: @dGRAMOP Wait until he asks for your resume. They may not have an internship at this time, if they even do them.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a reply acknowledging your email and at the same time showing no interest in engaging your services.

It's unlikely the owner has any further interest in you, he has passed the information on to his own developer.

Comment: Alright. Well, I forgot to mention that this email address is team@website.com, so I think it could be the owner. Sorry for not clarifying. I got the email address of a buisness card with one name on it, and a response with another name on it...

Comment: Probably a reply from their web developer then, either way no hint of any forthcoming work.